# How can I get from LAX to Hacienda Heights?

Tags: public-transport, taxis, lax

I'm going to land at LAX airport 9 PM on a Friday. I need to go the surrounding area of Hacienda Heights.
I checked the taxi fare, it's over 100 USD.
From what I know LA's public transportation is a joke even more in the evening.

What is the most cost / time effective was to go from LAX to Hacienda Heights ?

Comment: [Uber, but I'd give serious consideration to renting a car.](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Los-Angeles-Airport-LAX/Hacienda-Heights)

Comment: No need to bash LA— its train system is limited, but the buses are extensive and well-run. The trouble is that the bus is held in very low regard by most Americans. Anyway. you're traveling to a very suburban location almost 40 miles from the airport, so you'd have trouble in any city. If you weren't arriving so late, in fact, it would be quite easy from LAX— FlyAway bus to Union Station, then FootHill transit 493 to Puente Hills Mall, done in 2 hours and $13.90. That is a good sight easier than LGA to Pompton Lakes, and a good sight cheaper than LTN to Cambridge.

Answer (score 7):

There is the old fashioned way to do it ... shared airport vans.  Super Shuttle charges about $50, don't think there is an app for it, but you can book online ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest renting a car. LA is a car-based city.

Comment: I forgot to say. That's the only taxi I will take in LA. The rest of the time , a friend will drive me in LA :)

Comment: @RaymondChenon I should have such a friend.

Comment: In fact, he's a cousin :)